# Komma vor "bis"?

Tags: sentence-structure, comma

Wird vor "bis" ein Komma gesetzt? Hier ein paar Beispielsätze:

1. > Ich frage mich, ob sich das(,) bis ich aus der Schule raus(,) bin ändern kann.
2. > Mache das nun solange(,) bis du fertig bist.
3. > Du hast(,) bis Donnerstag dafür Zeit.

Sollte man die eingeklammerten Kommas setzen?

Answer (score 5):

Ein Komma wird gesetzt, wenn „bis“ einen Nebensatz einleitet. Das ist bei 3) nicht der Fall. Beim ersten Beispiel hast du den eingeschobenen Nebensatz allerdings nicht richtig erkannt.

> Ich frage mich, ob sich das, bis ich aus der Schule raus bin, ändern kann.

Answer (score -5):

Einfache Antwort. Nein.

> Da kannst du reden bis du schwarz wirst, und dann weiterreden bis du tot umfällst.

Comment: Doch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwarz_werden

Comment: Richtig geschrieben wäre das: »Du kannst **reden,** bis du schwarz wirst, und dann **weiterreden,** bis du tot umfällst.« Übrigens ist das Komma vor *und* in diesem Fall auch zwingend, weil es das zweite Komma ist, das einen Nebensatz paarweise einschließt. Bei »Du kannst reden und dann weiterreden«, ist es erlaubt aber nicht zwingend.